How to run Snakemake on an undetermined set of samples?
I am planning to create a Snakemake script that will run on a large scale data set. The script will:

preprocess the samples,
filter the samples based on the results of the preprocessing (note: all preprocessing samples are required for filtering)
proceed to the next step for samples that meet the condition.

But I dont know how to archieve this.
Here's the basic structure of my script:
sample = ['A', 'B', 'C']
rule all:
    input: 
        expand('output/pre_process/{sample}.txt', sample=sample)
        # I am not sure how to add the input 

# just a toy run
rule pre_process:
    output:
        'output/pre_process/{sample}.txt'
    shell:
        """
        echo "" > {output}
        """

rule filter: 
    input:
        expand('output/pre_process/{sample}.txt', sample=sample)
    output: 
        # all passed filter sample will in folder, one sample one file 
        directory('output/filter')
    shell:
        """
        # toy run
        cp output/pre_process/{{A,B}}.txt output/filter/
        """

rule process: 
    input: 
        # I need process samples in output/filter one by one
    output: 
        'output/data/{sample}.txt'
    shell: 
        """
        # just example, not run
        echo "" > {output}
        """

Note: cant get what sample need be furture process unless filter step output the files

I think what you need is a checkpoint which reevaluates the dag after the filter step.
Would this work:
def get_file_names(wildcards):
    ck_output = checkpoints.filter.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    SMP, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(ck_output, "{sample}.txt"))
    return expand(os.path.join(ck_output, "{SAMPLE}.txt"), SAMPLE=SMP)

def getFinalOut(wildcards):
    ck_output = checkpoints.filter.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    SMP, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(ck_output, "{sample}.txt"))
    return expand(os.path.join("output/data/", "{SAMPLE}.txt"), SAMPLE=SMP)

rule all:
    input: 
        expand('output/pre_process/{sample}.txt', sample=['A', 'B', 'C']),
        getFinalOut



# just a toy run
rule pre_process:
    output:
        'output/pre_process/{sample}.txt'
    shell:
        """
        echo "" > {output}
        """

checkpoint filter:
    input:
        expand('output/pre_process/{sample}.txt', sample=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    output:
        directory('output/filter')
    shell:
        """
        # toy run
        mkdir {output}
        cp output/pre_process/{{A,B}}.txt {output}
        """
rule process:
    input:
        get_file_names
    output: 
        'output/data/{sample}.txt'
    shell: 
        """
        # just example, not run
        echo "" > {output}
        """

Disclaimer: I never used checkpoints myself and just based it on this post here. So better double check it twice.
